# Checking if a number is perfect square?

Tags: c++

I think there is a precision problem with the following code:

```
bool isPerfectSquare(long long n){
    long long squareRootN=(long long)(sqrt(n)+0.5);

    return squareRootN*squareRootN == n;
}
```

How to fix it? 
**P.S: 1 <= n <= 10^10**

> Sqrt(4) could return 1.9999 => 1 so I added 0.5 so that it becomes 2
>   upon round off. Note: sqrt returns floating point.

This is an explanation that I found but still cant fix the code:

> Hi, it seems you are also an victim of floating point values. If
>   possible, you should always avoid floating point comparisons. It got
>   worst with the increase in range of numbers. Say, when you assign
>   float a=4.0 it is stored as 4.000...01111 or 3.999999...9978 or
>   similar. So be cautious whenever you also type case a square root to
>   an int. Possibility of these types of errors increases with the increase in the range of 
>   integer.

Comment: [This related question on math](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/41337/66531) may be informative.

Comment: Do you have any examples when it goes wrong? Because I can't see why this would fail...

Comment: This is not a trivial question, as the list of poor answers shows. People, please consider the range of input values, and the limited precision of floating-point numbers. In particular, if you do give an answer that "fixes" that limited precision, please show that the fix is sufficient but not overkill.

Comment: Your second quote is a poor example. 4.0 can and should be stored *exactly* in a floating point number. If it isn't then something is badly wrong. A better example would be 0.1 which can't be stored exactly in a floating point number.  (In general the question is fine, but the example is flawed)

Comment: @jcoder Got it here:https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/is-fibo/forum/questions/5560

Comment: Adding 0.5 to a floating point number before truncating it to an integer is a standard way to do that.  I don't see anything wrong with your code and I have checked every number up to 30000*30000 and the function doesn't return the wrong answer for any of them: https://wandbox.org/permlink/5wt41kscpuynTDQU   If you have an example where it doesn't work that would be useful.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the result of the floating point square root as a hint only. Convert it to an integer. Check if the square is equal. If it is higher or lower, decrement or increment it, then recheck for the square, and continue until you have bound the parameter with:
c1*c1 <= n <= (c1+1)*(c1+1)

Answer (score 2):

You might use std::sqrt as a guess and test with multiplication:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>

bool isPerfectSquare(long long n){
    double guess = sqrt(n);
    long long r = std::floor(guess);
    if(r*r == n) return true;
    else {
        r = std::ceil(guess);
        return r*r == n;
    }
}

int main() {
    const long long Limit = std::pow(10, std::numeric_limits<long long>::digits10 / 2);
    std::cout << " Limit: " << Limit << '\n';
    for (long long i = 0; i < Limit; ++i) {
        if( ! isPerfectSquare(i*i)) {
            std::cout << "Failure: " << i << '\n';
            return 0;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "Success\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You use `round`.

```cpp
bool isPerfectSquare(long long n) {
    long long squareRootN = (long long)round((sqrt(n)));
    
    if(squareRootN * squareRootN == n) {
        return true; 
    } else {
        return false; 
    }
}
```

`round` rounds the number to the nearest rounding. The function will be true only if n is a perfect square.

Comment: Consider `llround`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round

Answer (score 1):

mmmm don't use float/double for your true/false outcome (you'll end up having approximation problems)
Much better the integer apporach:

```
   boolean is_square(long long n)
   {
      long long a=n;
      while (a*a>n)
      {
         a=div(a+div(n,a),2);
      }
      return a*a==n;
   }
```

div() is the integer division without remainder (you can use GCD() in some ways)

I know, I know... care must be taken for overflow issues

Comment: You're right on the overflow part: n=10^10 **will** overflow.

Answer (score 1):

> Sqrt(4) could return 1.9999

No, 4 and 2 are exactly representable as binary floating point numbers. No precision problems there.

The problem is that `long long` has 64 bits of precision, but `double` has only 52, so all solutions that rely on calling `sqrt(double)` will start failing when you hit that limit. Here is a simple test program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

bool isPerfectSquare(long long n)
{
    double root = sqrt(n);
    return floor(root) == root;
}

void check(long long x)
{
    if (!isPerfectSquare(x))
        std::cerr << x << " should be perfect\n", exit(1);
    if (isPerfectSquare(x-1))
        std::cerr << x-1 << " should NOT be perfect\n", exit(1);
    if (isPerfectSquare(x+1))
        std::cerr << x+1 << " should NOT be perfect\n", exit(1);
}

int main()
{
    for (long long i = 2; i < 3037000499; ++i)
        check(i * i);
    std::cout << "all tests passed\n";
}
```

And here is the output on my computer:

```
4503599627370497 should NOT be perfect
```

Note that `log(4503599627370497)/log(2) = 52`. In case you don't care about numbers that large, you can use the simple solution that merely checks whether `sqrt` returns an integral result.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply check the floor and ceiling of `sqrt()`:

```
bool isSquare (long long number)
{
    double root = sqrt(number);
    double floor = std::floor(root);
    double ceil = std::ceil(root);

    return (floor * floor == number) && (ceil * ceil == number);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a range for your return boolean, although it may lead to unprecise outputs depending on how stringent your requirements are:

```
double threshold = 0.01;

return (squareRootN*squareRootN > n-threshold) && (squareRootN*squareRootN < n+threshold);
```

Comment: Since the input is integral, the output should be precise.

Comment: Yes, this is a workaround that only works if fore some reason you don't need exact precision in your boolean output.

Answer (score 0):

The code is fine!

I have taken the time to write a small test.
As the input range is limited, we can simply validate the function for every input.

Note that I did have to add an explicit cast to `double` for the `sqrt` function for it to compile (using MS VC++ 10).

```
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

bool isPerfectSquare(long long n){
    long long squareRootN=(long long)(sqrt((double)n)+0.5);

    return squareRootN*squareRootN == n;
}


int main()
{
    // for the input range,
    // generate a set with numbers that are known to be perfect squares.
    // all the rest are not.
    std::set<long long> perfectSquares;
    for(long long i = 1ll; i <= 100000ll; ++i) {
        perfectSquares.insert(i*i);
    }
    std::cout << "Created lookup." << std::endl;

    // now test the function for all the numbers in the input range   
    int progress = -1;
    for(long long i = 1ll; i <= 10000000000ll; ++i) {
        bool expected = (perfectSquares.count(i) == 1);
        bool actual = isPerfectSquare(i);

        if(expected != actual) {
            std::cout << "Failed for " << i << std::endl;
        }

        int newprogress = i / 100000000ll;
        if(newprogress != progress) {
            progress = newprogress;
            std::cout << "Progress " << progress << "%" << std::endl;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "Test finished." << std::endl;
}
```

Results? Pass for all values!
The problem must be in the code that uses the function.
Maybe add input range validation to the function.

Answer (score -2):

`long long` is an integer type. So, your +0.5 is lost in truncation.

Comment: I do not think this is correct, as the sqrt function returns a floating point value.

Comment: A floating point value that is added to the 0.5, ok, and then immediately truncated. So, assume it returns 0.3. Add 0.5. 0.8 is truncated to 0.

Comment: Sqrt(4) could return 1.9999 => 1 so I added 0.5 so that it becomes 2 upon round off. Note: sqrt returns floating point.

Comment: @SahilSareen, it's important to realize that type conversion in C truncates. It does not round.

Comment: @sam: Your 0.3 example is correct. It should be rounded down, so (0.3+0.5) => (0.8) => 0 is the correct rounding. The chief problem is with negative numbers, and that just doesn't matter here.

Comment: @MSalters, *ah*, yes, thank you. Because we spend the extra computation on the multiplication for validation it works out. Thank you.