# I want to check if sq. root of a number is int

Tags: c

this is not working :

```
for(int i=a;i<=b;i++)  
{      
    if(sqrt(i)==int) count++;  
}
```

What should I use?

Comment: of course it doesn't. Trying to guess the syntax of a language rarely does.

Comment: and this is completely backwards way to do this. Instead use a loop variable that *is* the square root, and **square** it and check if it is still within the limits.

Comment: Step 1.  Take the square root.  Step 2. Extract the fractional part of the square root.  Step 3. See if the fractional part is 0 or not.  [Steps 2 and 3 might be tricky.  See also alternative method in next comment.]

Comment: Step 1. Take the square root.  Step 2. Round off to the nearest int.  Step 3. Multiply that int by itself (square it).  Step 4.  See if you get the original number or not.

Comment: @SteveSummit "Extract the fractional part of the square root." and "See if the fractional part is 0 or not." is easy with `modf()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like below :

```
double a = 5, b = 25;
short count = 0;
for (double i = a; i <= b; i++) {
    double sqrut=sqrt(i); 
    if ((int)(sqrut) == sqrut) {
        printf("Perfect square %.0f found\n", i);
        count++;
    }
}
printf("Total number of perfect squares is %d\n", count);
```

or like below :

```
double a = 5, b = 25;
short count = 0;
for (double i = a; i <= b; i++) {
    int sqrut = sqrt(i); // An implicit casting happens here.
    if ((sqrut * sqrut) == i) {
        printf("Perfect square %.0f found\n", i);
        count++;
    }
}
printf("Total number of perfect squares is %d\n", count);
```

Comment: there's still the accuracy issue.

Comment: Indeed, I was making that change.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Indeed there is, and for the same reason, this is not a general solution to the problem.

Comment: @sjsam your method is wrong it is better to make int value squared and then compared

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach this is to truncate the root to an `int` and check if this affects the value:

```
double root = sqrt(i);
if ((int) root == root) {
    count++;
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't rely on that (accuracy issues). must be a duplicate, I found this for C++ (should work for C as well): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23558888/checking-if-a-number-is-perfect-square

Answer (score 0):

To see if a `double` has a fraction, use `modf()`

> The `modf` functions break the argument value into integral and fractional parts, C11dr §7.12.6.12 2

```
double root = sqrt(x);
double int_part;
if (modf(root, &int_part) == 0.0) puts("root is a whole number");
```

Note that `sqrt(x)` only provides the nearest  representable `double` to the mathematical square root of `x` and so may give approximately correct results as `root`.

Answer (score -1):

```
double iii = 4.0000000000000006;

double eee = sqrt(iii);

int fff = eee;

printf("%d\n", (int)eee == eee);    // returns 1 - which is incorrect

printf("%d\n", fff * fff == eee);   // returns 0  -- correct answer
```

Comment: okay Peter, but don't forget that the input is an integer in the current case.

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre but squaring the integer result is much more accurate in more general case

Comment: Agreed. And doesn't need using floating point... Noone proposed a correct solution, you could [edit] your answer to propose one (there are some answers, but they're for the c++ tag)

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre where is the c++ tag?

Comment: here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23558888/checking-if-a-number-is-perfect-square. That said, this question has 7 downvotes so far. I wouldn't invest in an answer...

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre but not in this question or maybe I am blind i see many questions with the C++ tag https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46016646/how-to-enable-c17-support-in-code-blocks but not this one

Comment: and how about rounding issues? truncating numbers? the question was about "should use"

Comment: every float method has an accuracy issue. Larger or smaller.