# how to Enable c++17 Support in code blocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks, c++17

in codeblocks There isn't a C++17 option in the Build or Compiler options, only C++14
how can i enable it in codeblocks so that both coding tools and compiler support it?

Comment: Pass `-std=c++17` as an option to the compiler (if using clang or gcc).

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch im working on a project which the new file system library of c++17 is really needed for it

Comment: Then avoid it and use the Boost equivalent. File systems API also exist in Qt or GTK or POCO, you could use these. On Linux you could just use the existing (and stable) system calls (`readdir`, `stat`, etc...)

Comment: i know but  im  more interested on using std  and my project is cross platform

Comment: Then wait a few years till that stuff has been matured

Comment: You could download mingw-w64 (GCC 7.2) and configure CB to use instead of the old GCC it comes with, then add the `-std=c++17` flag.

Comment: As of now, **Codeblocks** doesn't support C++17.

Comment: @ishpreet: Codeblock don't support any kind of C++; the C++ is processed by some compiler invoked by CodeBlkock

Answer (score 8):

[Code::Blocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code::Blocks) is *not* a compiler (but some glorified [source code editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code_editor), sometimes calling themselves [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment)s, which runs some external compiler).

You need a **C++17 *compiler*** (and once you've got one you might configure your IDE or editor to use it with the *appropriate* options). Try the very latest version of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) (at least [GCC 7](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-7/), and perhaps wait for GCC 8) or [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) (wait for Clang5) and [pass it](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) the `-std=c++17` option

Note that [C++17](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B17) is the C++ standard slated to be published by the end of 2017. You may need to wait a bit (perhaps a year or two) for compilers and the standard library implementations to correctly and completely implement it.

Therefore I don't recommend using C++17 features on a project to be released soon (at end of 2017), since you are then building on β quality foundations. However, if you work on a large project to be released in 2019, you might take the risk of betting that the C++17 features you are using in it will become mature by that time.

Regarding standard libraries functions (such as [std::filesystem](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem)) you'll easily find approximate equivalent (e.g. in native OS or POSIX APIs, in Boost, in Qt, in POCO, ...) that should be reasonably easy to port once C++17 implementations are common.

<sup>(I recommend using your compiler on the command line, or using [`make`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/), [ninja](https://ninja-build.org/), or some other [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) system running compiler commands; details can be operating system and compiler specific.)</sup>

Comment: Please recommend *anything* besides `make`. A build system like CMake, which is cross-platform would be a good recommendation.

Comment: `cmake` generate `Makefile`s

Comment: Sure, it's one thing it can generate. Realistically you wouldn't want to generate Makefiles anymore, but rather Ninja files, as they're superior in every way. You can also generate project files for many different IDEs. There's something fitting for every platform and taste.

Comment: Both GCC and Clang support all C++17 **language** features on their latest releases. There are a few missing standard library things, but they are usually fairly small.

Comment: Oh, also, Clang 4 doesn't support the `-std=c++17` flag, but Clang 5, which should be releasing this upcoming week, does.

Comment: @tambre: If by "fairly small", you mean the FileSystem, then yes, there will only be a "few" missing features. Neither libc++ nor libstdc++ implement the filesystem as defined in C++17.

Comment: @NicolBolas That's true. Actually `std::filesystem` is the only blocker preventing my code from compiling on both GCC and Clang (besides porting it to Linux). If I'm understanding correctly, then Clang 5, which is shipping this upcoming week, should support C++17 filesystem library in full (although some error resolutions aren't implemented).