# Which Version of Code::Blocks supports C++11, C++14 and C++17 Compilers?

Tags: c++, c++11, windows-7, c++17, codeblocks

Please give me the Version of Code::blocks, currently i'm using Code::Blocks 10.05 on Windows 7 with Server Pack 1 installed.  The Code::blocks i'm using does not support either of the three Compilers that i had mentioned above, Thank You.
[I'm not going to install VS, because of data limit, i atleast need C++11, so even if you Coders can give me that version of Code::blocks it would be more than enough]

Comment: Code::Blocks is the IDE. The compiler you use has the C++ language support not the IDE. I think you need to update your mingw version and activate c++11 or greater in the IDE.

Comment: Maybe update your Code:blocks....currently on 20.03. Maybe this version ships with modern compilers

Comment: Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18174988/how-can-i-add-c11-support-to-codeblocks-compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18174988/how-can-i-add-c11-support-to-codeblocks-compiler)

Comment: @drescherjm Code:Blocks 10.05 is from 2010. Doubt it supports compilers with support for C++11 and newer

Comment: @Thrasher i tried installing it, it didn't work ultimately in my device.

Comment: What compilers does it have? MinGW, clang, msvc? Which version? You can download and setup the new compiler in Compiler settings of code:blocks

Comment: ***it didn't work ultimately in my device*** Probably you need to ask for support at the Code::Blocks forum for installation issues with their software. [http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?board=1.0](http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?board=1.0)

Answer (score 2):

Definitely the latest version (20.03) which supports C++11, C++14, C++17 and even C++20, if the compiler allows it. If you always want a compiler updated to the latest standards (and upgradeable with a simple command from the shell), the advice is to install the compiler separately through the Msys2 toolchain.

Answer (score 0):

Code::Blocks can't compile your code. You need a newer version of the compiler, such as GCC or Clang.

For more information refer to: [How to Enable C++17 Support in Code Blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46016646/how-to-enable-c17-support-in-code-blocks#46016699).